# Python program with arguments on Windows

Tags: python, argparse

How to run this program saved in the file test.py on Windows XP with python 2.7 installed.

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Process some integers.')
parser.add_argument('integers', metavar='N', type=int, nargs='+',help='an integer for the accumulator')
parser.add_argument('--sum', dest='accumulate', action='store_const',const=sum, default=max,help='sum the integers (default: find the max)')
args = parser.parse_args()
print args.accumulate(args.integers)
```

I tried to run it with command line. For example

```
$ python test.py 1 2 3 4
```

or

```
$ python test.py 1 2 3 4 --sum
```

gives error "invalid syntax".

Comment: How about copying the exact and full error message 1:1?  Did you try using `$` as your first character?

Comment: The error is SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: `code` Python 2.7.8 (default, Jun 30 2014, 16:03:49) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>>> ================================ RESTART ================================
>>> 
usage: test [-h] [--sum] N [N ...]
test: error: too few arguments
>>> $ python test.py 1 2 3 4
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> python test.py 1 2 3 4
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> $ python test.py 1 2 3 4
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> python test.py 1 2 3 4 --sum
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> python test.py 1 2 3 4 --sum

Comment: Get out of the `python` interpreter.  Review your instructions on how to run a python program from a command window.

Answer (score 3):

I tried running your script at the command line and it works perfectly:

```
$ python arg.py 1 2 3 4 --sum
10
```

In the above, the `$` is the shell's prompt.  What I entered is `python arg.py 1 2 3 4 --sum`.  It works.

Now, let's do what I suspect that you are doing: let's start an interactive python shell and enter the above:

```
$ python
Python 2.7.12+ (default, Aug  4 2016, 20:04:34) 
[GCC 6.1.1 20160724] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> python test.py 1 2 3 4 --sum 
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    python test.py 1 2 3 4 --sum 
              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

This generates the `SyntaxError: invalid syntax` error that you see.  (There is one minor difference: I am on Linux and you are on Windows.)

The solution is to exit the python interactive shell and enter the command at the command prompt.

Comment: Ah! This actually is a variation I didn't consider - and given the vote known error this makes sense. :)

Comment: Unfortunately this is not working. The program which don't need arguments run fine.

Answer (score 0):

This is just me being naive, but considering the short error message you posted...

Any chance you're getting this code off some book and try to run this on a command line?

The book uses `$` to mark command line/terminal commands, but the character is actually not part of the syntax or command you're supposed to use.

So instead of running this:

```
$ python 1 2 3
```

Run this:

```
python 1 2 3
```

Comment: Still gets same error with python 1 2 3 or with  python test 123

Comment: @mathsbeauty Can you run `python --version`?

Answer (score 0):

Your `test` script is the first example on the Python argparse documentation.   https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html

Your comment with new lines added is

```
Python 2.7.8 (default, Jun 30 2014, 16:03:49) 
[MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32 
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information. 
>>> ================================ RESTART ================================ 
>>> usage: test [-h] [--sum] N [N ...] test: error: too few arguments 
>>> $ python test.py 1 2 3 4 
SyntaxError: invalid syntax 
>>> python test.py 1 2 3 4 
SyntaxError: invalid syntax 
>>> $ python test.py 1 2 3 4 
SyntaxError: invalid syntax 
>>> python test.py 1 2 3 4 --sum 
SyntaxError: invalid syntax 
>>> python test.py 1 2 3 4 --sum
```

From this I deduce that you saved the script as `test` ('test.py` would have been better), and ran it, from a Windows command line, as

```
python -i test
```

which produces

```
usage: test [-h] [--sum] N [N ...] test: error: too few arguments
```

That usage message from the `parser`; `test` is the name of the script.

I'm not sure about the `RESTART` line.  My tests (at the end) suggest your Python call (or some default environment feature) includes the `-i` option, which leaves you in the interactive Python session, even after the `argparse` step fails.

The next command is straight out of the Python example:

```
>>> $ python test.py 1 2 3 4 
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

But the context is all wrong.  The docs include `$` to indicate that this is being typed in a commandline (Linux shell or Windows commmand).  And the meaning, in the correct context is:

- run Python
- tell it to run the test.py script
- and pass it the arguments '1','2', etc

But if you are already inside a Python interpreter (indicated by the `>>>` prompt string), this does not make sense.  `python` and `test.py` are strings that don't have a default meaning inside Python.  So the interpreter gives you a syntax error.  And none of the variations fix that.

A little further along, the `argparse` documentation gives an example of calling a `parser` from within a Python interactive session:

```
>>> parser.parse_args(['--sum', '7', '-1', '42'])
```

That has a very different syntax.  In this `python -i` context it should run.

Going back to the Windows command window and typing

```
python test 1 2 3 4
```

has a better chance of working.  If that doesn't work, then you/we need to focus on running an even more basic Python script.

=========

Here's an example of running another simple script from a Linux shell.  The `...$` is the shell prompt; the `>>>` is the python prompt.  Adding the `-i` to the initial python call ensures it stays in python after parsing.

```
0957:~/mypy$ python -i simple.py
usage: simple.py [-h] foo
simple.py: error: too few arguments
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "simple.py", line 4, in <module>
    print(parser.parse_args())
   ...
SystemExit: 2
>>> python simple.py 1 2
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    python simple.py 1 2
                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

The main difference between my test and yours is that I don't get the `RESTART` and I get a traceback.  Without the `-i` I simply get the usage message and a return the command line.

```
1000:~/mypy$ python simple.py
usage: simple.py [-h] foo
simple.py: error: too few arguments
1000:~/mypy$
```